# Test only one it or describe with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

On TestUnit you can launch one test in file with -n option

for example

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end

  test "the truth 2" do
    assert true
  end

end
```

You can execute only the test the truth

```
ruby -Itest test/unit/user_test.rb -n test_the_truth
```

The ouput

```
1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skip
```

How can that with rspec ?

The command seem not work

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb -e "User the truth"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't include the source of your spec, so it's hard to say where the problem is, but in general you *can* use the `-e` option to run a single example. Given this spec:

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe User do

  it "is true" do
    true.should be_true
  end

  describe "validation" do
    it "is also true" do
      true.should be_true
    end
  end

end
```

This command line:

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb -e "User is true"
```

Will produce this output:

```
Run filtered including {:full_description=>/(?-mix:User\ is\ true)/}
.

Finished in 0.2088 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

And if you wanted to invoke the other example, the one nested inside the validation group, you'd use this:

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb -e "User validation is also true"
```

Or to run all the examples in the validation group:

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb -e "User validation"
```

Comment: I try again and it works ! I did not really understand what had happened .... but thank for your answer because it made ​​me go back on it!

Answer (score 2):

You can also select in which line is the test case you want to execute.

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb:8
```

By passing any line inside the scope of the test case, only this test case will be executed. You can also use this to execute a whole context inside your test.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Rspec 2.11.1 you can use all of the following options:

> **** Filtering/tags ****
>
> ```
> In addition to the following options for selecting specific files, groups,
> or examples, you can select a single example by appending the line number to
> the filename:
>
>   rspec path/to/a_spec.rb:37
>
> -P, --pattern PATTERN            Load files matching pattern (default: "spec/**/*_spec.rb").
> -e, --example STRING             Run examples whose full nested names include STRING (may be
>                                    used more than once)
> -l, --line_number LINE           Specify line number of an example or group (may be
>                                    used more than once).
> -t, --tag TAG[:VALUE]            Run examples with the specified tag, or exclude examples
>                                  by adding ~ before the tag.
>                                    - e.g. ~slow
>                                    - TAG is always converted to a symbol
> ```